# Pylint disagrees with file import

Tags: python-2.7, pylint

In reference to [How do I import a Python script from a sibling directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py/27876800#27876800), Pylint will error with **`E0401`:Unable to import** at line 6.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
if __package__ is None:
    import sys
    from os import path
    sys.path.append(path.dirname(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))))
    from components.core import my_module
else:
    from ..components.core import my_module
```

Is this just something that we have to accept, or is there a rigorous solution to correct this?

While the file in question is part of my unit tests and not critical to deployment, I would like to keep everything error free.

(pylint 1.6.4, Python 2.7.12)

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` located in the directory you're importing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to importing *components*, then this would not work, since pylint does not understand modifications of sys.path. It would be theoretically feasible to understand them, but since it is a static analysis tool, it has its limitations with regard to what it can and what it should do. In order to help it, you might try running pylint with *--init-hook="import sys; sys.path.append(path.dirname(path.dirname(path.abspath('your file'))))"*.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you for the explanation.